# Yii2 - Direct Login to action that calls action update

Tags: php, yii, arguments, yii2

**Greetings**

**I have 3 categories of users, admin, socio and atleta.**

**What i want is to Login as atleta and enter directly to the update form of that user**

**The problem is that when i make Login as atleta, it calls the actionAtleta inside the UserController but always throws error -> Bad request #400 Missing required parameters: id**

Here is my sitecontroller code:

```
public function actionLogin()
{
    if (!\Yii::$app->user->isGuest) {
        return $this->goHome();
    }

    $model = new LoginForm();
    if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->login() && $model->user->categoria == 'admin') 
        {
            return $this->goBack();
        } 
    else if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->login() && $model->user->categoria == 'socio')
        {
            $this->redirect(Url::toRoute(['user/socio']));
        }
    else if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->login() && $model->user->categoria == 'atleta')
        {
            $this->redirect(Url::toRoute(['user/atleta']));
        }
    else {
        return $this->render('login', [
            'model' => $model,
        ]);
    }
}
```

And... Here it is my actionAtleta, inside UserController:

```
public function actionAtleta($id)
{
    $model = $this->findModel($id);

    if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->save()) {
        return $this->redirect(['view', 'id' => $model->id]);
    } else {
        return $this->render('update', [
            'model' => $model,
        ]);
    }
}
```

**I tried several more ways of passing the $id, but it always throws Missing id error when making login**

**Anyone knows why ??**

**Many thanks**

**EDIT**
**If i make public function actionAtleta($id=3), it enters the actionAtleta and brings the form to update for the model id = 3. But what i want is that it detects at login wich id is trying to make login and then fire the _form to update whatever the logged user needs.**

Comment: $this->redirect(Url::toRoute(['user/atleta'.$Yii::$app->user->id])); is not working? What have you tried?

Comment: It throws error:  Unable to resolve the request: user/atleta3.
The id user i try to login has id = 3.

Comment: well i forgot the slash there, $this->redirect(Url::toRoute(['user/atleta/'.$Yii::$app->user->id]));

Comment: Didn't solved. It throws: Unable to resolve the request "user/atleta/3".

Comment: Many thanks for the try Jorgen. It was close :))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should simply add user `id` param to route, e.g. :

```
if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->login()) {
        switch($model->user->categoria) {
            case 'admin' :
                return $this->goBack();
                break;
            default : 
                return $this->redirect(['user/'.$model->user->categoria, 'id'=>$model->user->id]);
        }
}
```

And don't forget that you need to **return** $this->redirect().

Comment: SOLVED. Many thanks Soju, your code put me in the right path. I write it like -> $this->redirect(Url::toRoute(['user/atleta/', 'id'=>$model->user->id]));

Comment: You don't need Url::toRoute here

Comment: Can you explain me the diference? What does Url::toRoute does. I think it calls actions inside controllers. Am i understanding wrong? Thanks for the answer...

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
$this->redirect(Url::toRoute(['user/atleta/'.$Yii::$app->user->id]));
```

and update your urlManager in config to

```
'urlManager' => [
        'rules' => [
            'user/atleta/<id:\d+>' => 'user/atleta',
        ]
    ],
```

Comment: Routes should be well constructed (independent of url rules).